# Best way to implement conditional expression based on numeral value (positive, negative, zero)

Tags: c++, if-statement, optimization

Is there a better eleganter way to implement the naive following code (diffYear, A, and B are numerals):

```
diffYear = yearA - yearB;

if (diffYear == 0) {
    A = B = 0;  
}
else if (diffYear > 0) {
    A = diffYear * -1;
    B = 0;
}
else if (diffYear < 0) {   // obviously one could only write a simple else, this is for the sake of the example
    A = 0;
    B = diffYear;
}
```

Comment: `if (diffYear == 0)`is in fact unneeded, as both cases would produce `A = B = 0;` anyway.

Comment: I think for readibility diffYear variable is unnecessary. `if (yearA > yearB)` is better imo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This implementation is fine.

> Is there a better eleganter way to implement the naive following code

The rule of thumb is: is it clear what it's doing? If yes, leave it.

---

Other implementation would be possible too, but you must take into account who will be reading this code. For instance, in a team/organization were most developers use maths everyday, I'd write something like the following to appear more "natural" to them:

```
auto neg(int x) { return x < 0 ? x : 0; }
//...
int const A = neg(yearB - yearA);
int const B = neg(yearA - yearB);
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
template<typename T>
std::pair<T, T> neg_diff(T a, T b) {
    if (a < b)
        return {0, a - b};
    else
        return {b - a, 0};
}

const auto [A, B] = neg_diff(yearA, yearB);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Jarod pointed out in comment, maybe you could just write it as:

```cpp
A = B = 0;  
diffYear = yearA - yearB;
if (diffYear > 0)
    A = diffYear * -1;
else if (diffYear < 0)
    B = diffYear;
```

note the `else if(yearA < yearB)`, just an `else` is wrong cause we removed the first one.

Answer (score 0):

What is 'better' or 'more elegant' is somewhat subjective, IMHO. However, you could reduce the amount of code using the (ternary) [conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other):

```cpp
diffYear = yearA - yearB;
A = (diffYear < 0) ? 0 : diffYear * -1;
B = (diffYear < 0) ? diffYear : 0;
```

(Note that, as pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59771225/best-way-to-implement-conditional-expression-based-on-numeral-value-positive-n/59771430#comment105686131_59771225), when `diffYear == 0` both `A` and `B` will be set to zero, 'automatically').

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use min and max. I'm not sure this is more readable in this situation, but there are some contexts where it is.

```
A = -std::max(diffYear, 0);
B = std::min(diffYear, 0);
```

(Also note that, in general, I would expect variables to be initalised when they're created. In your original code, you could initialise them to 0, and cut those lines out of the if blocks)

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know the type(s) involved in the comparison, I prefer to use only `<` since that's usually the first, and sometimes only, comparison operator implemented in custom classes.

```
diffYear = yearA - yearB;

if(diffYear < 0) { // negative diff
    A = 0;
    B = diffYear;
} else {           // the rest of the diffs
    A = -diffYear; // was: A = diffYear * -1
    B = 0;                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = min(yearB - yearA, 0);
B = min(yearA - yearB, 0);
```

Comment: Including an explanation with this answer would help other users understand how this is meant to answer the original question.